# How can I produce a table with column headers from org-babel shell output?

Tags: org-babel

I'm trying to add headers to this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir ~ :results table
  for n in 1 2 3 4; do
      echo $n $(($n * $n))
  done
#+END_SRC
```

Which results in:

```
#+RESULTS:
| 1 |  1 |
| 2 |  4 |
| 3 |  9 |
| 4 | 16 |
```

The output I want is:

```
#+RESULTS:
| N | N*N |
|---+-----|
| 1 |   1 |
| 2 |   4 |
| 3 |   9 |
| 4 |  16 |
```

The difficulty I'm having is injecting the second line. This does not work:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir ~ :results table
  echo "N N**2"
  echo "|-"
  for n in 1 2 3 4; do
      echo $n $(($n * $n))
  done
#+END_SRC
```

This results in:

```
#+RESULTS:
| N | N**2 |
|   |    - |
| 1 |    1 |
| 2 |    4 |
| 3 |    9 |
| 4 |   16 |
```

Neither can I just use a blank line, as suggested [here](https://gist.github.com/elationfoundation/2a7d36b2bb4f57c7ac74):

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir ~ :results table
  echo "N N**2"
  echo 
  for n in 1 2 3 4; do
      echo $n $(($n * $n))
  done
#+END_SRC
```

As this results in:

```
#+RESULTS:
| N | N**2 |
|   |      |
| 1 |    1 |
| 2 |    4 |
| 3 |    9 |
| 4 |   16 |
```

Any hints greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `:results org` is what you're looking for, and then make your code output what you'd type yourself as a table with separators (quoted to protect from the shell)

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir ~ :results org
  echo "|N|N**2"
  echo "|-"
  for n in 1 2 3 4; do
      echo "|" $n "|" $(($n * $n))
  done
#+END_SRC
```

That produces this (emacs 25.1.50.1, org 8.3.3):

```
#+RESULTS:
#+BEGIN_SRC org
| N | N**2 |
|---+------|
| 1 |    1 |
| 2 |    4 |
| 3 |    9 |
| 4 |   16 |
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: This is close, but when exporting this it shows verbatim. However, if you use `:results org drawer` rather than just `:results org` then it exports as a nice table :-)

Comment: BTW, did you just join to answer this? Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Great question and answer. Still, it would be useful to be able to just add headers to rows and columns as a post-processing step and not to depend on your particular language to take care of that.